Does/will Disney World charge men 20% more for tickets?
I saw a news post that Disney World is going to charge men 20% more than women to "fight the wage gap".
I can only find it on Mouse Trap News, which looks like a parody site, but there's nothing on the page that I can see that says it's a joke. It could also be a Disney related news site.
This seems like discrimination and a major lawsuit. Is this true?

At the bottom of the linked news post: To stay up to date on more very real Disney news like this totally made-up story

Also on the About page: From Disney Park announcements to Disney Hotel and resort news to made-up Disney partnerships, you can be assured that anything you read here is not true, real, or accurate, but it is fun.

Voting to close, because nobody is actually claiming this.


but there's nothing on the page that I can see that says it's a joke.

https://mousetrapnews.com/about/
The entire website is a joke site and they are quite open about it.

What is Mouse Trap News?


Mouse Trap News is the world’s best satire and parody site.

Why would you think this is real? Unfortunately the vast majority of websites are NOT a reliable source of factually correct information and I recommend doing at least rudimentary fact checking before taking anything seriously.
